# unable to multiply matrices above 32*32 size in CUDA

Tags: matrix, cuda

I am trying to implement matrix multiplication using CUDA. I have two matrices of order M*w and w*N. I launched (w*w) threads in each block and grid dimension = (M/w,N/w). I created a matrix in shared memory of size 32*32. I want to implement matrix multiplication using only one matrix in shared memory. Here's my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<math.h>

__global__ void add(int *a,int *b, int *c,int *p,int *q){

    // __shared__ int aTile[*p][*p];
    //const int a=*p;
    __shared__ int aTile[32][32];

    int row = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int col = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int sum=0;
    aTile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = a[row*(*p)+threadIdx.y];

    __syncthreads();
    if(row< *q && col< *q) 
    {
        for(int k=0;k<*p;k++)
        {
            sum+= aTile[threadIdx.x][k]*b[col+(*q)*k];
            // __syncthreads();
        }

        c[col+(*q)*row]=sum;
        //__syncthreads();
    }
}


int main(){
    printf("Enter the number of rows of matrix 1\n");
    int row_1;
    scanf("%d",&row_1);
    printf("Enter the number of columns of matrix 1\n");
    int col_1; 
    scanf("%d",&col_1);
    /*printf("Enter the values of matrix 1 \n");
     */
    int a[row_1][col_1];
    for(int i=0;i<row_1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col_1;j++)
        {
            //scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            a[i][j]=1;
        }
    }

    printf("Enter the number of rows of matrix 2\n");
    int row_2;
    scanf("%d",&row_2);
    printf("Enter the number of columns of matrix 2\n");
    int col_2;
    scanf("%d",&col_2);
    /*  printf("Enter the values of matrix 2 \n");
     */
    int b[row_2][col_2];
    for(int i=0;i<row_2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col_2;j++)
        {
            //  scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
            b[i][j]=1;
        }
    }

    int c[row_1][col_2];
    //dim3 dimBlock(col_1, col_1);// in one block u have row_1*col_2 threads;
    dim3 dimBlock(col_1,col_1);
    //dim3 dimGrid((row_1/col_1)+1,(col_2/col_1)+1); // in one grid you have 1*1 blocks
    dim3 dimGrid(ceil(row_1/col_1),ceil(col_2/col_1));
    int *p;
    int *q;
    int *dev_a,*dev_b,*dev_c;
    int size_a=row_1*col_1*sizeof(int);
    int size_b=row_2*col_2*sizeof(int);
    int size_c = row_1*col_2*sizeof(int);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a,size_a);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b,size_b);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c,size_c);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&p,sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&q,sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a,a,size_a,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b,b,size_b,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c,c,size_c,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(p,&col_1,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(q,&col_2,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    add<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c,p,q);
    cudaMemcpy(c,dev_c,size_c,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    printf("output matrix is : \n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I get the correct output for when i multiply matrices of size 32*32 and 32*32
but when i Multiply matrices of sizes 33*33 and 33*33(and above) , the resultant multiplied matrix contains all zeros. I have tried to increased the size of matrix in shared memory, but I get the following error

```
ptxas error   : Entry function '_Z3addPiS_S_S_S_' uses too much shared data (0x10038 bytes, 0x4000 max)
```

I am pretty new to CUDA. Sorry, if this was too much basic question

Comment: Please fix the formatting of you code. It is just about unreadable as posted.

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic question and has been answered many times over.

1. First of all, use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code.  In this case, you would have received an error that would have been instructive.
2. CUDA kernels have a limit on the maximum number of threads per threadblock.  That limit (under CUDA 7, 7.5RC, currently) is 1024 threads per block, on all supported devices.  The number of threads per block is specified (in this case) by your `dimBlock` variable, and it is the *product* of the terms in each dimension:

   ```
   dim3 dimBlock(col_1,col_1);
   add<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c,p,q);
   ```

Therefore, when `col_1` is 32, you are requesting 32x32 threads (1024) which is the maximum.  Any value above 32x32 will fail for this reason. (Your kernel will not launch.  No kernel code will get executed when you specify 33x33 here.)

Rather than rewrite this code to fix all the issues, I suggest you study any of the dozens of questions already asked about matrix multiplication, here on the cuda tag.  In fact, if you want to see a shared memory optimized code for naive matrix multiplication in CUDA, there is a full example in [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory) (including both the non-shared version and the shared version for comparison).

And again, I suggest you implement [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) before asking for help here. Even if you don't understand the error results, it will be useful information for those who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an overflow in this line:

`aTile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = a[row*(*p)+threadIdx.y];`

knowing that `aTile` is defined as `__shared__ int aTile[32][32];`

If you want to do tiling, you'll have to loop over the number of tiles you need to cover your matrice.

Comment: How can that be a overflow? The maximum number of threads per block is 1024, so any block size which could actually run won't overflow a 32*32 shared memory allocation using that indexing scheme

Comment: I got that alright. Indeed, another bug prevents this one from showing up. But this is a bug all the same FMPOV.